# NCO download Python

Tags: python, nco

There is not much help on troubleshooting the outside package NCO for netCDF4 files when downloading. I am following the steps from https://github.com/jhamman/nco-bindings. The first step is to `run setup.py install` and I was able to see it install. Below is the end of the output saying it installed.

```
Installed c:\users\...\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site- 
packages\nco-0.0.2-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for nco==0.0.2
Finished processing dependencies for nco==0.0.2
```

but I am running into a problem when Running operators. The step is:

```
From nco import Nco
nco=Nco()
```

and I get an error for `nco = Nco()`saying

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

meaning there is nothing within that function. I am using Enthought Canopy for python but I do not think that is a problem. Any help on getting function like `ncra` running would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem and I solved it by defining a new system variable called "NCOpath" and I did set its value to the path of nco package (in my case the path is "C:\nco").

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The Python NCO wrappers require that NCO already be installed (in order to wrap them). Is the TypeError you encounter because the wrappers cannot find the NCO executables? Windows NCO binaries are [here](http://nco.sourceforge.net/src/nco-4.4.8.windows.mvs.exe)

Comment: I am working with jupyther notebook in windows 10. I installed the binaries that you mentioned, I create a new environmental variable, I have also tried https://sourceforge.net/p/nco/discussion/9830/thread/59fe446d/ and so far, it keeps saying the same ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nco'.  I  dont know what elese to do

Comment: Try installing the NCO binaries from conda instead: conda install -c conda-forge nco